# PHP/HTML Change Text if Dropdown Menu option is checked

Tags: php, html

I'm working on like a Shop Page, where you can choose how long you want to buy the service.

There is a Dropdown Menu with 3 Options:

- `1 Week`
- `3 Weeks`
- `6 Weeks`

How can I do :

If the option `3 Weeks` is clicked, the price(simple text) automatically changes to `5 dollars` and `6 Weeks` to `10 Dollars` or something like this?

All price changes are done by me.

I would like to know how can I change `exampletext1` to `exampletext2` by choosing something from my dropdown menu ?

Comment: You can use JavaScript/jQuery for this.

Comment: Please add what have you done so far?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0fF0AuAd  This is my whole script, the drop-down menu "produkt" or "Produkauswahl" is what i want to get the info from

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LmD7jSy3 This is bether

Comment: Do u want to extract the value using PHP server side script ?

Comment: I dont really mind, i just want it to work, im not that advanced into PHP, i would highly appreciate if someone could just tell me how it works :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Client side**

To modify your page on client events (example:click, select change) without reloading all the page, you have to use a client side langage like `JavaScript`.

**Server side**

`PHP` is used only on server side. It's means that `PHP` is executed before your page is sent to user and can't catch action from user without send a new request to the server (and reload the page).

**Here is the example you asked (with javascript)**

https://jsfiddle.net/9c1unscw/1/

```
<p>Select a period.</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="1">1 Week
  <option value="2">3 Weeks
  <option value="3">6 Weeks
</select>

<p id="demo">Estimated price: 5 dollars.</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
      var price = parseInt(x)*5;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Estimated price: " +price+" dollars.";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a small algorithm that will give you a basic idea:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

  <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="one">1 Week
      <option value="three">3 Week
        <option value="six">6 Week
  </select>

  <p id="price">Price: 1 dollars</p>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      /*
      You should get this price array from your PHP service dynamically
      whenever this page is requested.
      */
      var price = [];
      price['one'] = '1';
      price['three'] = '5';
      price['six'] = '10';


      var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
      document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "Price: " + price[x] + " dollars";

    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```